# Error: plt.hist(df1.Score A), Python Pandas/Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

My Code:

```
plt.hist(df1.Score A)

File "<ipython-input-14-dff3e3378235>", line 2
    plt.hist(df1.Score A)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is resulting in the above error. Can you suggest how to solve this? I think since there is a "Space" in the Column Name : **"Score A"**, it is giving an error.

Comment: use `plt.hist(df1['Score A'])`

Comment: Is that a space between Score and A.  They you can't use the dot notation.  You must use df['Score A'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
plt.hist(df1['Score A'])
```